# Accessing TradeKing (or any pre-authorized API) with C#/.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oauth

When setting up an application with TradeKing, you get:

- A Consumer Key
- A Consumer Secret
- A Oauth Token
- A Oauth Token Secret

For accessing TradeKing's API, that's apparently [all you need to build personal applications](https://developers.tradeking.com/documentation/oauth). However, I can't find a way to build the correct Oauth headers in C#/.NET.

The examples seem fairly simple, [like this Node.js sample](https://developers.tradeking.com/documentation/node). The Oauth library for Node.js takes care of generating the appropriate headers. There are similar samples for a few other languages, but they all seem to have libraries to build the proper header from the provided keys and tokens. I can't find a library to do this with C#/.NET.

I'm trying to wrap my head around what's going on [in this SO question that builds the headers from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706133/create-oauth-signature-with-hmac-sha1-encryption-returns-http-401), but it's pretty advanced. I'm poking around in the [ASP.NET Security repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Security), because they must be handling this somewhere. But I can't quite find what I'm looking for.

How can I generate an Oauth header from these keys with .NET?

Comment: have you checked this http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/a-simple-guide-to-using-oauth-with-c-/49

Comment: @Yordan I had stumbled across that when in my web searches, but ignored it because the [code it referenced](http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72088#Cropper.Plugins/TwitPic/OAuth.cs) was from 2010 and had a poor rating on Codeplex. But with a couple changes I was able to plug it in to my app. Thanks for the push.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open source library on CodePlex](http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/72088#Cropper.Plugins/TwitPic/OAuth.cs) that has some Oauth management classes set up.

I still need to go through it and take out what isn't necessary, but fortunately it doesn't depend on any other classes from the repo. Once I added it to my project, it was pretty easy to test the connection:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MakeRequest()
{
    string result;
    var oauth = new Oauth.Manager();
    // _tradeKing is a configuration object I set up to hold user secrets
    oauth["consumer_key"] = _tradeKing.ConsumerKey;
    oauth["consumer_secret"] = _tradeKing.ConsumerSecret;
    oauth["token"] = _tradeKing.OauthToken;
    oauth["token_secret"] = _tradeKing.OauthTokenSecret;

    var url = "https://api.tradeking.com/v1/accounts.json";
    var authzHeader = oauth.GenerateAuthzHeader(url, "GET");
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = authzHeader;
    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return Content(result);
}
```

There are some more instructions on how to use it from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002847/oauth-with-verification-in-net).