# Generate hmacsha1 signature for RestSharp oauth1.0 C# (no token)

Tags: c#, restsharp, hmacsha1

So I have this header for my authorization:

```
 string oAuthHeader = string.Format("OAuth oath_consumer_key=\"{0}\",oath_signature_method=\"{1}\",oath_timestamp=\"{3}\",oath_nonce=\"{4}\",oath_version=\"{5}\",oath_signature=\"{2}\"", _consumerKey, OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1, GenerateSignature(), GenerateTimeStamp(), GenerateNonce(), Version);
```

Which gets added here:

request.AddHeader("Authorization", oAuthHeader);

Been seeing a few demos on this, but they all include the token. In this case, there is no token, just key and secret. How would I go about generating the hmacsha1 signature?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706133/create-oauth-signature-with-hmac-sha1-encryption-returns-http-401 help?

Comment: @mjwills I've been looking at that plus a few other questions to see if I can extract anything from other people's questions. My problem is that I lack very little knowledge on this subject, so while maybe that sample might be helpful, I wouldn't know how to modify it for my needs.

Comment: OAuth is a "dance". [These samples should be helpful](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp.IntegrationTests/oAuth1Tests.cs).  You'll see the "token dance" [starting here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp.IntegrationTests/oAuth1Tests.cs#L56) in the Twitter sample. Hth..

Comment: Is it not more often referred to as a "handshake"?

Comment: Nice one @Thymine :) Yup..but dancing is more fun :)