# How to include query params in the base string signature OAuth1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, gravity-forms-plugin

I need to retrieve some data through the gravity forms API (which is installed as a plugin in a WordPress server). I must implement OAuth 1.0. Some of the ruby gems available for this type of authentication don't work pretty well for me, so I decided to implement it myself.

I'm able to sign the base string if I don't add extra params but once I add them I get the error `Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.`

My code looks like this:

```
# This OAUTH implementation works without extra query params.
require 'httparty'
OAUTH_TOKEN = "API customer secret token"
OAUTH_PASSWORD = "API customer key token"

url = 'https://localhost/wp-json/gf/v2/entries'

params = "oauth_consumer_key=#{OAUTH_TOKEN}&oauth_nonce=#{SecureRandom.hex}&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=#{Time.now.to_i}&oauth_token=#{OAUTH_PASSWORD}&oauth_version=1.0"
base_string = 'GET&' + CGI.escape(url) + '&' + CGI.escape(params)
secret = "#{OAUTH_PASSWORD}&#{}"
oauth_signature = sign(secret, base_string)
testable_url = url + '?' + params + '&oauth_signature=' + oauth_signature

response = HTTParty.get(testable_url)

def sign( secret, base_string )
  CGI.escape(Base64.encode64("#{OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha1', secret, base_string)}").chomp)
end
```

But once I add the query params I need, it crashes.

```
query_params = 'search={"field_filters":[{"key":"'+form['key']+'","value":"'+email+'","operator":"is"},{"key":"source_url","value":"'+form['source_url'].to_s+'","operator":"is"}]}'
```

I'm updating the base_string to include the query_params then I sign it again and I update the final url

```
base_string = 'GET&' + CGI.escape(url) + '&' + CGI.escape(query_params) + '&' + CGI.escape(params)
oauth_signature = sign(secret, base_string)
testable_url = url + '?' + query_params + '&' + params + '&oauth_signature=' + oauth_signature
```

As a result I get the following URL

```
"https://localhost/wp-json/gf/v2/entries?search={\"field_filters\":[{\"key\":\"2\",\"value\":\"some@email.com\",\"operator\":\"is\"},{\"key\":\"source_url\",\"value\":\"https://localhost/some_url_i_need/\",\"operator\":\"is\"}]}&oauth_consumer_key=APICUSTOMERSECRET&oauth_nonce=81a6ce4dcabd5ec1059f66ca7ae727e3&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1607594914&oauth_token=APICUSTOMER_TOKEN&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=LIZpR27KNHsw3iWArJjSs%2FsvIek%3D"
```

Which doesn't work due to the `Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.` error.

As suggested in the documentation and other posts I've read (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789210), I've sorted the params (basically I added `search` param I need at the end of the base string and that didn't solve my issue.

Note: It works in Postman, and the URL that Postman generates is pretty much like the one I get with Ruby.

Comment: Could you paste URL which postman generates?

Comment: ```"https://localhost/wp-json/gf/v2/entries?search={\"field_filters\": [{\"key\":\"2\",\"value\”:\”some@email.com,\”operator\":\"is\"}, {\"key\":\"source_url\",\"value\":\"https://source_example.com/\",\"operator\":\"is\"}]}&oauth_consumer_key=CONSUMERKEY&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1607771258&oauth_nonce=Nw4R2icbtxi&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=7wR/c0PMJlX/GVac76A5vkJM+Z8="```

Answer (score 2):

One of your issue is that you forgot to escape the ampersand between your `query_params` and regular `params`:

```
base_string = 'GET&' + CGI.escape(url) + '&' + CGI.escape(query_params) + '&' + CGI.escape(params)
```

You have to turn that last `'&'` into `'%26'` or pull the concatenation into the `CGI.escape`.

```
base_string = 'GET&' + CGI.escape(url) + '&' + CGI.escape(query_params + '&' + params)
```

Watch out for empty `params` though with this.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the issue either.

Comment: At least it will be part of the puzzle